# About union of two algebraically independent sets

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, transcendental-numbers, rationality-testing

My question might be very simple for those that have a deep understanding for algebraically independent sets.

**Definition 1.1**. Let $F$ be an extension field of $K$ and $S$ a subset of $F$. $S$ is algebraically
dependent over $K$ if for some positive integer $n$ there exists a nonzero polynomial
$f\in K[x_1, . . . , X_n]$ such that $f(s_1, . . . , s_n) = 0$ for some distinct $S_1, . . . , s_n\in S$. $S$ is
algebraically independent over $K$ if $S$ is not algebraically dependent over $K$.

Let $P_1\cup P_2$ are two algebraically independent sets of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ and $P_1\cap P_2=\emptyset.$ Assume there exist $a,b\in\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ such that $P^*=aP_1+b\subset J$ for some open interval $J$ subset of $\mathbb R$ Does the following hold ?

**I**. $P^*$ is algebraically independent ?

**II**.  $P^*\cup P_2$ is algebraically ?

Clearly, **I** is correct since $q P_1$ is algebraic and shifting algebraically independent by rational number is still algebraically independent set.
About, **II** I do not find an example that shows it is incorrect or proof it. I am tried to find algebraic depending relation between elements of $P^*\cup P_1$

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Should there be additional conditions in **II**? Take $\{\pi\}$ and $\{e^\pi\}$, they are algebraically independent and their union is independent. Take $\{\sqrt\pi\}$ and $\{2\pi +1\}$, they are algebraically independent but their union is dependent.

Comment: @RandyMarsh, I think, this would not work in this case because I am assuming $P_1\cup P_2$ is algebraically independent. In your example, $P_1=\{\sqrt\pi\}$ and $P_2=\{\pi\}$ but $P_1\cup P_2$ is algebraically dependent.

Comment: Where do you assume that $P_1\cup P_2$ is algebraically independent? This assumption is not written anywhere, unless I am mistaken

Comment: @RandyMarsh, I am sorry. I fixed. How about now? Does it work ?

Comment: Assume $P^*\cup P_2=\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n\}$ is dependent with $\alpha_i \in P^*$, $\beta_i\in P_2$ and for simplicity assume $P^*\cap P_2=\emptyset$. Then there is a non-zero polynomial $f(x_1,\dots,x_m,y_1,\dots,y_n)$ over $\mathbb Q$ vanishing on $P^*\cup P_2$. Take $g=f(\frac{x_1-b}{a},\dots,\frac{x_m-b}{a},y_1,\dots,y_n)$.  Then $g$ vanishes on $P_1\cup P_2$.

Comment: @RandyMarsh, the same what I did. Any reference that you know has more advance facts about algebraically independent . Thank so much

Comment: Algebraic independence appears in many contexts (algebra, geometry, combinatorics etc), so it depends what you are interested in. A starting point is Van Der Waerden's Modern Algebra I, section 64.